# Intuition for Fisher information metric

Tags: statistics, riemannian-geometry, information-theory

In statistical maniolds $S=\{p_\theta\}$,$\theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$, the Riemaanian metric usually defined is the Fisher information metric $$g_{ij}(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\int \partial_i(\log p_\theta) \partial_i(\log p_\theta)~p_\theta~dx$$

The associated connection coefficients are defined by $$\Gamma_{ij}^k=\int \partial_i\partial_j(\log p_\theta)\partial_k (\log p_\theta)~ p_{\theta}~dx$$

My question is, what is the intuition behind defining these? Is there a way to **prove using the above metric and connection** that the linear family of probability distributions $$L=\{p:\int f_i(x)p(x)~dx=m_i, i=1,\dots,k\}$$ intersects "orthogonally" the associated exponential family $$\mathcal{E}=\{p:p(x)=c(\theta)q(x)\exp(-\sum_{i=1}^k\theta_i f_i(x))\}$$ in the sense that $L\cap\mathcal{E}=\{p^*\}$ where $p^*$ satisfies $$D(p\|q)=D(p\|p^*)+D(p^*\|q)$$ for every $p\in L, q\in \mathcal{E}$.